# Sort the array of strings in C?

Tags: c

```
int my_compare( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    char* str1 = (char*)a;
    char* str2 = (char*)b;

    return strcmp( str1, str2 );
}

int main()
{
  char d[5][10];

  strcpy( d[0], "123456789");
  strcpy( d[1], "1");
  strcpy( d[2], "7");
  strcpy( d[3], "200000");
  strcpy( d[4], "300400000");

  qsort( d, 5, sizeof(char*), my_compare );
}
```

This doesn't seem to be OK.

How do I sort the array of strings in this case?

Comment: The size of each element is `sizeof d[0]` (which is `10`), not `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: Each element in `d` is not a `char*` but a `char[10]`. This means that the size-parameter you pass to `qsort()` should be `10` or better `*d`

Comment: What *specifically* does "This doesn't seem to be OK." mean?  What were you expecting?

Comment: Your code would be correct if it were `char *d[5];` and you then did `d[0] = "123456789"; ...`

Comment: Changing the qsort line to `qsort( d, 5, 10, my_compare );` fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `sizeof(char*)` is the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8 depending on your platform), but you need to provide the size of one element which is 10.

In the following code the all sizes (maximum string length and number of strings) are calculated with the the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator.

Explanation:

- `int maxstrlength = sizeof(d[0]);` : this is the size of one string element (10 in your case)
- `int nbofstrings = sizeof(d) / sizeof(d[0]);` : this is the number of elements (or strings). IOW the total size of `d` (50 here) divided by the size of one element (10) which is 5.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int my_compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  const char* str1 = (const char*)a;
  const char* str2 = (const char*)b;

  return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

int main()
{
  char d[5][10];

  strcpy(d[0], "123456789");
  strcpy(d[1], "1");
  strcpy(d[2], "7");
  strcpy(d[3], "200000");
  strcpy(d[4], "300400000");

  int maxstrlength = sizeof(d[0]);
  int nbofstrings = sizeof(d) / sizeof(d[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < nbofstrings; i++)   // display strings before sorting
    printf("d[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, d[i]);

  printf("\n");

  qsort(d, nbofstrings, maxstrlength, my_compare);

  for (int i = 0; i < nbofstrings; i++)   // display strings after sorting
    printf("d[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, d[i]);
}
```

BTW: in `my_compare` the pointers should be casted to `const char*` rather than `char*`, but this is nitpicking.